# How to load data from a .csv flat file into a SQL Server table inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, csv, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a requirement of loading data from a `.csv` file into a SQL Server table inside a stored procedure. We even thought of implementing a SSIS packages, but we had some limitations and have left with only stored procedure.

I even have got the functionality using bulkinsert, where its not accepted in our project.

So requesting to provide any alternate method for data loading.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like  : 
https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/09/t-sql-read-csv-files-using-openrowset

Is this acceptable ?